# sqlalchemy pyramid query keyerror

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, orm, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am working on a project that loads local data onto a local server using SQLAlchemy and a pyramid framework.  The following describes the setup:

-The local data are divided in multiple CSV files

-A separate SQL object (called DataSource) is created from each individual CSV file

-The parent of all DataSources is also a DataSource.  Thus all CSV data are children

So, the parent DataSource is created, then all the children DataSources are created and linked to the parent.  A separate function checks if the DataSource already exists.  If not, it is created.

So, firstly we create the parent DS:

```
sName = 'Parent DS'
oDS = fetch_or_create_data_source(name=sName,author="Parent_DS_author"
```

)

Then we loop through all CSVs and create the children DS:

```
for sCSV_name in lCSVs:
    oChildDS = fetch_or_create_data_source(name=sCSV_name,parent=oDS)
```

Here is the problem:

fetch_or_create_data_source creates a keyerror on the second iteration of CSV loading.  So the parent and the first child DataSources are created without a problem.  The error log below is created on the second child DS.  A new DS should be created, since no there exists no DS with the given parent and name.  All CSV filenames are unique.
Can anyone see why I get a mysterious key error on the second iteration of the DS creation?  I could not find anything on the webs.

(EDIT):  I know the error is created in `lDS = list(oDS.filter_by(name=name).filter_by(parent=parent))`, but I do not understand why, especially after the first two times it runs without a problem.  I changed the code so that the parent_id is called instead of the parent object, but the KeyError persists.  The error is caused by any `filter_by()` statement.  To check for primitive values, I added some print statements to check the arguments in fetch_or_create_data_source.  The results:

```
name = 'Parent DS' type <type 'str'>
author = 'Parent_DS_author' type <type 'str'>
parent = None
Current DS id = '352' type <type 'int'>
.
.
name = 'tab19' type <type 'str'>
author = '' type <type 'str'>
parent = <pyramidapp.models.DataSource object at 0x7fcb28066b50>
parent_id = 352 type <type 'int'>
Current DS id = '353' type <type 'int'>
.
.
name = 'tab42' type <type 'str'>
author = '' type <type 'str'>
parent = <pyramidapp.models.DataSource object at 0x7fcb28066b50>
parent_id = 352 type <type 'int'>
```

When I explicitely state that oDS is None, the key error originates from DBSession.flush() in the 3rd iteration.

Why would the first two instances of fetch_or_create_data_source run without problems, but the third not?

Code and traceback:

```
fetch_or_create_data_source:

def fetch_or_create_data_source(name,parent=None,author=""):
    from pyramidapp.models import DBSession,DataSource
    oDS   = DBSession.query(DataSource)

    print "name = '{0}' type {1}".format(name,type(name))
    print "author = '{0}' type {1}".format(author,type(author))
    print "parent = {0}".format(parent)
    if parent:
        print "parent_id = {0} type {1}".format(parent.id,type(parent.id))

    if parent is None:
        lDS = list(oDS.filter_by(name=name).filter_by(parent_id=parent))
    else:
        lDS = list(oDS.filter_by(name=name).filter_by(parent_id=parent.id)) <=== Key error from here

    if len(lDS)==0:
        oDS = None
    else:
        oDS = lDS[0]

    if not oDS:
        oDS = DataSource()
        oDS.name = name
        if parent:
            oDS.parent = parent
            if parent.author:
                oDS.author = parent.author
        if author:
            oDS.author = author
        DBSession.add(oDS)
        DBSession.flush()

        print "Current DS id = '{0}' type {1}".format(oDS.id,type(oDS.id))

    return oDS



Pyramidapp.models.DataSource:

    class DataSource(Base):
        """
        this represents a release of data. It may be a group of documents
        or a single spreadsheet
        """
        __tablename__   = 'data_sources'
        id              = Column(Integer,Sequence('data_src_seq'),primary_key=True)
        name            = Column(String(100))
        notes           = Column(Text)
        title           = Column(String(100))
        author          = Column(String(100))   
        parent_id       = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('data_sources.id'))
        parent          = relationship('DataSource',backref=backref("children",cascade="all, delete"),remote_side=[id,])
        .
        .
        ...




    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-2.0.2-py2.7.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/panels/performance.py", line 55, in resource_timer_handler
    result = handler(request)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5b1-py2.7.egg/pyramid/tweens.py", line 21, in excview_tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.7-py2.7.egg/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 82, in tm_tween
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.7-py2.7.egg/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 63, in tm_tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5b1-py2.7.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 163, in handle_request
    response = view_callable(context, request)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5b1-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 355, in rendered_view
    result = view(context, request)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5b1-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 477, in _class_requestonly_view
    response = getattr(inst, attr)()
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/pyramidapp/pyramidapp/views/basic_views.py", line 108, in run_ds_script
    oScript.run(dSettings)

  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/pyramidapp/pyramidapp/scripts/data_source_specific/load_prescriptions_dispensed_in_the_community_data.py", line 82, in run
    oChildDS = fetch_or_create_data_source(name=sCSV_name,parent=oDS)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/pyramidapp/pyramidapp/tools/data_source_script_tools.py", line 22, in fetch_or_create_data_source
    lDS = list(oDS.filter_by(name=name).filter_by(parent_id=parent.id))

  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2397, in __iter__
    self.session._autoflush()
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1184, in _autoflush
    self.flush()
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1879, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1997, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 57, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1961, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 370, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 523, in execute
    uow
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 64, in save_obj
    mapper, table, insert)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 594, in _emit_insert_statements
    execute(statement, params)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 717, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 317, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 814, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 927, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1079, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 920, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 425, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyMySQL-0.6.1-py2.7.egg/pymysql/cursors.py", line 93, in execute
    escaped_args = tuple(conn.escape(arg) for arg in args)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyMySQL-0.6.1-py2.7.egg/pymysql/cursors.py", line 93, in <genexpr>
    escaped_args = tuple(conn.escape(arg) for arg in args)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyMySQL-0.6.1-py2.7.egg/pymysql/connections.py", line 698, in escape
    return escape_item(obj, self.charset)
  File "/home/roman/Critical_ID/big_data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyMySQL-0.6.1-py2.7.egg/pymysql/converters.py", line 24, in escape_item
    encoder = encoders[type(val)]
KeyError: <class 'pyramidapp.models.DataSource'>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start from the very end of the traceback and go a few lines up, you'll see that the error is raised in the PyMySQL lib when it tries to escape the value - supposedly it has some kind of a dict called `encoders` which contains a mapping of encoders. It looks like it fails when passed an instance if `pyramidapp.models.DataSource` class.

Surely, PyMySQL knows nothing about SQLAlchemy declarative classes and can only escape primitive types (ints, strings etc). So it's kinda unexpected it even sees the DataSource instance instead.

From your code samples it's not quite clear what causes the problem, but my best guess would be that you're either assigning a class instance to an attribute which is supposed to hold a primitive value, or maybe using a class instance in a query where it expects a primitive value. Something like this:

```
ds = DataSource(...)
other_ds.parent_id = ds  # instead of .parent
```

or

```
session.query(DataSource).filter(DataSource.parent_id==ds)
```

Actually, here it is:

```
lDS = list(oDS.filter_by(name=name).filter_by(parent=parent))
```

Comment: Hi Sergey.  Thank you for your reply.  I made some edits to my code, but I still cannot find the issue.  I checked whether all my arguments are primitive, and they are.  parent_id is always an integer, name is always a string.  Your code `other_ds.parent_id = ds` would assign the object ds to `parent_id`, which must be an integer.